# define implicit conversion from Int

Tags: scala, types, type-conversion

I am trying to define implicit conversions from scala ints to a custom Datatype.

Here are my functions

```
object DatabaseInt extends ImplicitConverter [Int]{

    implicit def fromContent(content: Integer): DatabasePrimitive[Int] = DatabaseInt(content)

    override implicit def fromContent(content: Int): DatabasePrimitive[Int] = DatabaseInt(content)

    override implicit def toContent(el: DatabasePrimitive[Int]): Int = el.getContent
}
```

This only seems works for scala primitive ints. Here is my test:

```
 val x: DatabaseInt = 3 //does not work
 val y: DatabaseInt = Int(3) //does work
 val z: DatabaseInt = Integer.valueOf(3) //does not work
```

Comment: What's `DatabasePrimitive`?

Comment: Thank you! I just returned the wrong type (the type of the superclass)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare the return type properly, it compiles just fine:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

trait DatabasePrimitive[A] {
  def getContent: A
}
case class DatabaseInt(i: Int) extends DatabasePrimitive[Int] {
  def getContent = i
}

object DatabaseInt {
    implicit def fromContent(content: Integer): DatabaseInt = DatabaseInt(content)
    implicit def fromContent(content: Int): DatabaseInt = DatabaseInt(content)
    implicit def toContent(el: DatabasePrimitive[Int]): Int = el.getContent
}


 val x: DatabaseInt = 3 // works
 val z: DatabaseInt = Integer.valueOf(3) // works
```

Your code didn't compile because your return types of `fromContent` were `DatabasePrimitive[Int]` instead of `DatabaseInt`. You therefore either have to adjust the return type of `fromContent`, or the types of `val x` and `val z`. Requiring a specific `DatabaseInt`, and at the same time returning a generic `DatabasePrimitive[Int]` doesn't work.